# What's the difference between (いちば/しじょう) for 市場?

Tags: word-choice

Does it refer to two different types of markets?
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"いちば" is a real place, e.g.

- [魚市場]{うおいちば} (fish market)
- [青果市場]{せいかいちば} (fruit and vegetable market)
- etc.

"しじょう" is the abstraction, e.g.

- [国内市場]{こくないしじょう} (domestic market)
- [労働市場]{ろうどうしじょう} (labor market)
- [金融市場]{きんゆうしじょう} (financial market)
- etc.

***Exceptions:***

- [中央卸売市場]{ちゅうおうおろしうりしじょう} (central wholesale market)
- others (in the field of finance often "しじょう")

Comment: Isn't 「中央卸売市場」 「ちゅうおうおろしうりしじょう」？