# Reading/speaking of 「市場」, which one can I use kun'yomi or on'yomi?

Tags: spoken-language

I came across the word [市場], which means market. In google translate the reading is 'Ichiba' but when I played the sound it gave me the sound 'shinjyou'.

I am aware that there are two readings for a character, i.e. kun'yomi (native japanese) and on'yomi (from chinese).

Though I am not sure which one to use when speaking/reading it, or is it ok to use both interchangeably?

Thank you!

Comment: The word has two possible readings, which mean different things. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21712/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%81%B0-%E3%81%97%E3%81%98%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-for-%E5%B8%82%E5%A0%B4

Comment: I prefer jisho.org over google translate when it comes to word definitions.  You can find both definitions here in a way that describes what you're looking for (if the other comments weren't enough) http://jisho.org/search/%E5%B8%82%E5%A0%B4